# Facebook post on a wall from a wordpress website

Tags: php, facebook

I need to make a button that on click posts a php generated text on that persons wall... can anybody give me some tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To start with there are different ways of posting something to a users wall, the common ways today are:

1. The user Like/Recommend something, in your case a blogpost. [See documentation here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
2. Make the user share a story on their wall through "Post to Wall". [See the documentation here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)
3. You create an open graph activity for your site. The Guardian have this so when a user reads an news article the article shows up as read in a "The Guardian" box on their profile. This solution is the far most complex and you find [the documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/).

The far most simple solution to implement is the "1. Like/Recommend". All you need to do is to set open graph meta tags to your PHP generated text on your "blog post single page", and then add like buttons that use a reference to the blogpost URL.

The other solutions kind of require that the user go through the [Facebook Authentication process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) which might scare them from sharing your content.

But if you aren't an developer I would probably recommend that you use some kind of "social plugin" to Wordpress.

I usually don't use Wordpress plugins, but you can try to search for "Social" and "Facebook" in their [plugin database](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

Read about the `Post` graph object here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/